# Read CSV with semicolons into a String on Java

Tags: java, csv

My main problem is that I'm trying to read a CSV delimited by `;` in Java and the problem comes when I try to read a field of the CSV that contains a `;`. For example:

> "I want you to do that;"

In this case the field is recognized like

> "I want you to do that"

And it creates another field that is just an empty string.
I use a `BufferedReader` to read the CSV and the `split` method to separate it with the `;`. I'm not allowed to use libraries like OpenCSV so I want to find a solution with the method I'm using.

Comment: Your input is wrong. Nothing you can do about that

Comment: You cannot have an unescaped delimeter in your column data. This is a problem within your data.

Comment: Are the semicolon-containing fields in your file quoted? How does the format of your file distinguish delimiters from semicolons in the content?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I believe the field should be quoted instead (i.e. `someField;"I want you to do that;";someOtherfield`).

Comment: It sounds like the CSV is perfectly fine, if it’s quoting data which contains a semicolon.  The problem here is that you cannot use `split` for this.  It’s not going to work.  Parse the line yourself and don’t use a regular expression at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Parse according to the quotation marks

If the data incidentally containing the delimiter is wrapped in double quotes ([QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm)), then you should have no problem with parsing. Your parsing should look first for pairs of double quote characters. After that, look for delimiters outside of those pairs.

Rather than writing the parsing code yourself, I highly recommend using a CSV library. In the Java ecosystem, you have a wealth of good products to choose. For example, I have made successful use of [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

See also the specification for [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values): [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Comment: This is 90% correct, but you also have to look for escaped quotation marks within the quoted string and skip them.